# Response 400 in HTTP request

Tags: python-3.x, http, http-headers

I am using requests module to post a dataframe df. However, it is showing <Response [400]>
{"name":"Bad Request","message":"Bad format for Authorization header"}. Here are my code-

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

dict_list = df.to_dict(orient='records')
data = dict_list[0]
resp = requests.post(URL,headers=headers,auth = HTTPBasicAuth(API_KEY, ''),data=json.dumps(data))
```

I have used the exact format to post a csv. But that time it worked fine without any error. Not sure what is wrong with this case